# Cannot Attach Database to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 just now and wanted to attach my previous databases. Attaching a Database gives an error.

> Attached is the image of the error.

[image]

Any Suggestions and help will be appreciated. :)
Regards.

Comment: Upgrade database version?

Comment: how do i upgrade it to SP1? i think upgradation is required..

Comment: Show to us that you did install SQL Server 2008 R2 by doing SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') or SELECT @@VERSION and post the output.

Answer (score 4):

Something seems not quite right with your question.

SQL 2008 is version 655
SQL 2008R2 is version 661

I would expect that you would only see that error if you are attempting to attach a 2008R2 DB to 2008, not vice versa.

As soon as you attach a DB to 2008 R2, the version is changed to 661 and can no longer be attached to a 2008 server.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL Server Management Studio install may be SQL 2008 R2, but I'm guessing your SQL Server database engine is SQL 2008.